# How do I check git log for a "fast-forward" merge?

Tags: git

In the following example, is there a way to know a merge happened?  Looking at git log, I can't tell I merged.

```
# setup example directory
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m "1"

# switch to different branch
$ git checkout -b topic
$ touch b
$ git add b
$ git commit -m "2"

# go back to master and merge
$ git checkout master
$ git merge topic

# git log

commit cccc64de3947828f487a8ce3c3e72b0f68dc88c3
Author: none
Date:   Fri May 20 05:54:45 2011 -0700

    2

commit a5d57454295759609d91a60219002e74016eed2b
Author: none
Date:   Fri May 20 05:54:29 2011 -0700

    1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In that instance, git has spotted that it's possible to do a so-called "fast-forward" merge, since the branch you're merging in already contains everything in the current branch - it doesn't need to create a new commit in the commit graph to join the two branches.

If you don't like that behaviour, and want create a merge commit even when fast-forwarding is possible, you should merge in the other branch with:

```
git merge --no-ff topic
```

However, if you *really* need to know whether a merge happened or not, you can find that information in the "reflog".  For example, in your situation, `git reflog` would produce the following output:

```
1eecbcb HEAD@{0}: merge topic: Fast-forward
193ae5e HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from topic to master
1eecbcb HEAD@{2}: commit: 2
193ae5e HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to topic
193ae5e HEAD@{4}: commit (initial): 1
```

... which shows you how `HEAD` was changed recently, and what action caused that to happen.  However, relying on the reflog is generally a bad idea except in particular situations, such as recovering from errors - it's better to just think in terms of the commit graph, and make that represent what you've done.  `git merge --no-ff` is one such method that lots of people like.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  Looks like git reflog only shows my local activity.  I'm using GitHub - is there a way to know if someone else did a fast forward merge?

Comment: @suravi no, unless they told you. A fast-forward merge is just like no merge at all.

Comment: Thanks its very helpful, but as you told Fast-forward merge occur when both branch code are same right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use git merge-base:

```
git merge-base master topic
```

It will show the `cccc64de3947828f487a8ce3c3e72b0f68dc88c3` ( 2) commit

Or you can use:

```
git show $(git merge-base master topic)
```

Comment: Good way to find out _where_ a merge happened, but doesn't help much with the _if_, because you wouldn't know the name of the topic branch in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try a case where you have a real merge, you could run the following commands after `git checkout master`:

```
touch c
git add c
git commit -m "3"
git merge topic
```

That is, you add a commit to the master branch. Then the graph of commits is no longer a linear sequence, and data has to be merged from multiple branches.