# Get commit messages of feature branch after merge

Tags: git

How can I get all commit messages of feature branch after merge (eg. to "develop" branch)?

I tried:

```
git log testbranch...develop --pretty=oneline
```

but it doesn't work.

Tree:
[image]

"Commit1" and "Commit2" are commits of "testbranch" which is already merged into develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, for the simple case, list commits accessible from `testbranch`, but not from `develop`:

```
git log testbranch ^develop --no-merges --pretty=oneline
```

That should be the same as `develop..testbranch` (two dots, not three)
See:

- "[What are the differences between double-dot “`..`” and triple-dot “`...`” in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6309)"
- "[What are the differences between double-dot “`..`” and triple-dot “`...`” in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)"

If `testbranch` has been merged back to `develop`, especially in a fast-forward manner, an empty result is expected.
Meaning: once a branch has been fast forwarded into another, there is no stating point anymore:

```
d---d--t--t--t (testbranch)
    |
(develop)

git checkout develop
git merge testbranch

d--d--t--t--t (testbranch, develop)
```

You don't know anymore "where" `testbranch` started.

If you did branch out with `testbranch` yourself (that is, in your local repo) not too long ago (less than 90 days), you can check out the [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) output, to get back a trace of the new `testbranch` event at `<sha1>`.
See "[How do I check `git log` for a “fast-forward” merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6072375/6309)".
Try:

```
git reflog show testbranch
```

Then, knowing where that branch started, you can list the commits with:

```
git log develop ^<sha1>
```

In your case, you might "know" that `testbranch` started at commit1, but my point is: Git alone would not know that (except locally in the reflog, if that branch was created in said *local* repo)

Comment: I tried `git log testbranch..develop --no-merges --pretty=oneline` but output is empty.

Comment: And `testbranch ^develop`? Should be empty too. Don't forget your question mentions `master`, not `develop`. And do you see commits in `testbranch` which are not in develop? Does `git branch -vv` lists local branches (not remote tracking branches) `testbranch` *and* `develop`?

Comment: Yes `testbranch ^develop` is empty too. Testbranch is merged to develop (I add image to my question). Result of `git branch -vv` contains both branches.

Comment: @JaSHin Yes, if that branch is merged to develop, an empty result is expected.

Comment: Is there a way to get commit messages after merge?

Comment: @JaSHin I don't see any commit after merge in develop. Do you see any commit you want to list in your tree?

Comment: d394f82 is last commit. I need result with "Commit1" and "Commit2". Testbranch started with "Commit1".

Comment: @JaSHin I have edited my answer to explain where to find where Testbranch started.